# Making GridView Respond to 2 Drop Down Lists

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have got 2 `DropDownList`s on my `Form` and 1 `GridView`. I want the `GridView` to display the data according to the selection from the `DropDownList`s.

For Example, One `DropDownList` contains Names and another contains Dates. Both the `DropDownList`s can post back. So if I select a name from 1st `DropDownList`, the `GridView` should show all the results according to that Name. Similarly if i select the `Date` from the other `DropDownList` , the `GridView` should show the results according to the dates. But i cant figure out as how to bind `GridView` to respond to 2 `DropDownList`.

BTW i am binding both the Drop Down Lists and the Grid View to the DataSource Objects, which is getting data from the database.

Any Suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better and cleaner if You use two `DataSource` with selecting data from db, and binding each of them to the `DropDownList`. I tried in my ASP.NET app do what You want but unfortunatelly I have erorrs :/

My only sollution is to don't use `DataSouce` in aspx file, but in `DropDownList` `SelectedItem` event use `DataContext` and it's possible that then you could bind both to the same `DataView` like below. I am not sure, but maybe You must use null in `DataSource` to reset `GridView` before use new data source:

```
protected void btPokaz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    var DzieciGrupa = from p in db.Dzieckos
                where p.Grupy.Numer == Convert.ToInt32(this.dropListGrupy.SelectedValue)
                orderby p.Nazwisko
                select new { p.Imie, p.Nazwisko };
    if (DzieciGrupa.Count() == 0) this.Label1.Text = "W " + this.dropListGrupy.SelectedValue.ToString() + " grupie nie ma dzieci zapisanych!";
    this.GridGrupy.DataSource = null;
    this.GridGrupy.DataSource = DzieciGrupa;
    // this.GridView1.DataSourceID = String.Empty;
    this.GridGrupy.DataBind();
```

Try it and tell say that works ;)

Comment: I am using 2 different DataSources for my DDL and both the DDLs are also autopostback. Can you please explain your code a little.

Comment: In my code i don't use DataSource creating in aspx class. In project I create Entity Data Model class. During creating this class You see a wizard which help You select Your DataSource. EDM class is a Object Model of the Data Source I use(i use SQL SERVER database, but You can use object, database etc as a source of data).  Then You use a DataClass which inherit from DataContext. DataContext is Model of Your source data. Next I use Linq to SQL to query data i need. At the end i "reset" GridView source and set my query data as Grid source and bind it ;)

Answer (score 0):

For Your problem You should create dwo EDM class for each data source. And simple in DDL select event Your choose of DataContext depends from user choose in DDL.

Example :

> ```
> protected void DDL_SelectedItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     TypeOfQueryData query = null;//you must know what type is data You query
>     if(this.dropListGrupy.SelectedValue==someItemSelect)
>     {
>     DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
>      //query to get data from source
>     query= from p in db.Dzieckos
>                 where p.Grupy.Numer == Convert.ToInt32(this.dropListGrupy.SelectedValue)
>                 orderby p.Nazwisko
>                 select new { p.Imie, p.Nazwisko };
>     }
>     if(this.dropListGrupy.SelectedValue==otherItemSelect)
>     {
>      DataClasses2DataContext db = new DataClasses2DataContext();
>      query= from p in db.Dzieckos
>                 where p.Grupy.Numer == Convert.ToInt32(this.dropListGrupy.SelectedValue)
>                 orderby p.Nazwisko
>                 select new { p.Imie, p.Nazwisko };
>     }
>     this.GridGrupy.DataSource = null;
>     this.GridGrupy.DataSource = DzieciGrupa;
>  //   this.GridView1.DataSourceID = String.Empty;//maybe You need do that
>     this.GridGrupy.DataBind();
> ```